# How to train a Keras model on CNN and Gist data, in the same time?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a dataset of only features extracted from a CNN (array of 4096), concatenated with another array of 512 of Gist data of images (total of 4602 features per sample). The features extracted of 2D images (scenes) I don't have access to the images, only their features. The goal is to train a classifier that can tell if a scene is memorable or not (So 2 categories).

The problem is:

- No matter what model architecture (Using Dense and Dropouts with all sorts of parameters) I use, my model always ends up biased to only one category (classifies all 0 or all 1). The accuracy stays in 70%, while the loss gets below 1.0

Things I tried:

- Different parameters for the layers
- Different number of hidden layers
- different loss functions (binary_crossentropy, sparse_categorical_crossentropy, mean_squared_error...)
- Different optimizers with different learning rates ranging from 0.0001 to 0.01 (Adam, SGD)
- I tried training on the first 4096 CNN features only as well as the 512 Gist features only. and both concatenated.

Notes:

- The features are extracted from the CaffeNet last Conv layer.
- This model is going to be used on features extracted with the same CaffeNet layer.

Comment: What was the softmax accuracy when normally training on CNN? Did you conduct any dimensionality reduction beforehand classification with dense?

Comment: The issue is that I don't have access to the original images, only the features extracted from the fc7 layer of the CaffeNet. And I have other features I want to classify. For dimensionality reduction, no I took the 4096+512 array and pluged it directly into the Dense classifier.

Comment: Please keep in mind that my dataset contains only 1200 samples and it's very biased towards one category by 1/6 ratio. I tried dealing with that using class weight.